# regular expression to capture a word regardless of lower or upper cases

Tags: javascript, java, regex, linux

I am trying to extract a word from a given string. The word can be `java`,`JAva`, `JAVA` etc. How can I write a regular expression which does not care lower or upper case. In other words, I do not want to use something like

`(java|Java|JAVA)`

If the word has a lot of characters, it is impossible to list all of the possibilities.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using flag `i`. It stand for case insensitive.

**Regex:** `/java/gi`

**Flags used:**

- `g` for global search.
- `i` for case insensitive.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yU0yK9/1)**</kbd>

Comment: `java` matches the characters java literally (case insensitive)

`g` modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)

`i` modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])

Comment: @MilindGokhale: I don't follow you sir. What are you trying to say ? OP is looking for different combination of **particular** word.

Comment: Nope, Looks like we both put the Flag information at the same time. You missed it first so I tried to give it.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you can use `(?i)(java)`.